# Por qual razão o auto-complete do VS Code não funciona para elementos da biblioteca UnityEngine mesmo com a extensão intalada?

Tags: c#, unity-5

O problema é justamente esse, estou desenvolvendo um jogo iniciante pela Unity e uso o Visual Studio Code como editor, e preciso do auto-complete para ajudar, porém mesmo com as extensões "Debugger for Unity", "Unity Tools" e "Unity Code Snippets" o problema é o mesmo, já tentei o Ctrl + space e nada. Segue um exemplo, onde na linha 12 não consigo escrever o conteúdo da linha 11 pelo auto-complete.

```
  using UnityEngine;
  using System.Collections;
  using System.Collections.Generic;

  public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
  {

  void Start(){

    //  ACESSAR UM COMPONENTE DO OBJ
    GetComponent<CapsuleCollider2D>(); 
    GetCo // ... O ERRO ESTÁ AQUI ;-;
  }

  void Update(){

  }

 }
```

Comment: Você instalou o `.Net Core` e o `C# Extension`?

Comment: Sim, ambos instalados.

Comment: Comigo também aconteceu isso, tentei varias coisas, então instalei o visual studio community 2019, apos ter feito isso o VSCode começou a funcionar perfeitamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara, eu consegui entender exatamente o que está acontecendo. Eu preciso fazer um vídeo explicando isso, é muito importante, tive que criar um projeto do zero aqui e para um dos projeto a minha extensão não funcionou, dai eu tive que descobrir a fundo como funcionava. E ENTENDI EURECA!

Seguinte, para o intellisense funcionar ele precisa de um cara chamado OmniSharp, para ativar esse cara você precisa apertar Ctrl+Shift+P e digitar OmniSharp, assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém antes você vai primeiro, fechar seu projeto indo em File > Close Folder e então com o VS Code sem nenhum projeto aberto você vai fechar ele. Dai vai abrir novamente e ai sim abrir seu projeto, e só depois fazer o procedimento de Ctrl+Shift+P e digitar OmniSharp e vai escolher a opção Restart OmniSharp.

POOOXA VIDA, AINDA NÃO FUNCIONOU!

Sim, aconteceu comigo também, ai tem a outra opção, Select Project...

Essa opção na verdade é para você escolher a solução do Projeto como um todo, o que te remete ao primeiro problema, se não tiver vinculado os projeto dotnet à solução, o Intellisense realmente não vai funcionar bem para aquele projeto (O VISUAL STUDIO .NET FAZIA ASSIM TAMBÉM) Dai você precisa vincular os projeto como eu mostrei nas aulas anteriores.

Ai garanto, se não funcionar, bota fogo no PC e compra um MAC. hehehe

Brincadeira, ai vai funcionar!